# Slackware on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, slackware

I have an iso image for slackware 14.1 and i want to boot it on GCE. Can anyone please guide me in doing so. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Google Compute Engine is not ready to allow standard images, you need to install your iso image in a VM in your machine using VMWare, Qemu or Virtualbox. Then, modify the VM a bit [following these steps](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#buildingimage).

After that, you can [upload the image to Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#exporting_an_image_to_google_cloud_storage) and finally add the image to your project using the command:

```
gcloud compute images create IMAGE_NAME --project PROJECT --source-uri gs://BUCKET_NAME/IMAGE_NAME.image.tar.gz
```

Once you have added the image you can create a new VM either using the Developers Console or the command-line.